# Unable to execute windows command line command with file name having multiple spaces as a parameter

Tags: java, windows, filenames, executable

I'm trying to execute pdf2html with params with all absolute path's. same command working fine by command prompt but giving error via java. Here is the code snippet that I'm using.

```
String command = pdf2html5ex_file_path + 
                    " --decompose-ligature 1 --tounicode 1 \""  + 
                    _curr_pdf_file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                    "\" \"" + 
                    _input_html_file_name + 
                    "\" --dest-dir \"" + 
                    removeEnd(_input_html_folder_path,"\\") + 
                    "\" ";
String Perms = _curr_pdf_file.canRead()?"Readable":"Non-Readable";
Perms += ";"+ (_curr_pdf_file.canWrite()?"Writable":"Non-Writable");
Perms += ";"+ (_curr_pdf_file.canExecute()?"Executable":"Non-Executable");
System.out.println("Permissions : "+Perms);
System.out.println("Command: "+command);
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Execute command
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

Exception message:

```
Permissions : Readable;Writable;Executable
Command: E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\PDFBOX\WorkSpace\libs\pdf2htmlEX\pdf2htmlEX.exe --decompose-ligature 1 --tounicode 1 "E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\input\pdf\TM  11.pdf" "TM  11.html" --dest-dir "E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\input\html" 
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\input\pdf\TM 11.pdf': File exists.
Error: Cannot read the file
Parsing completed for : TM  11.html
Unable to process record E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\input\pdf\TM  11.pdf
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\input\html\TM  11.html (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:37)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:88)
    at Parser.pdf2html(Parser.java:213)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:33)
```

in above output, trying to print command that is going to ex execute, which is showing correct file path as string but second line showing unable to read file with wrong path (two spaces are not there).

can somebody explain whats happening here?

Comment: The error says "FileAlreadyExistsException: E:\BackUpDisk\eTextCo\bookpad\Process\1\unprocessed\pdf\TM  11.pdf" even if this name is not mentioned in the printed command, which is strange. Also, you'd better use the Runtime.exec() version which accepts an array of strings, so that it will escape the parameters for you

Comment: You should be using `ProcessBuilder` it's much easier to pass parameters containing spaces with that